# QML Symbian components for desktop applications

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Is it possible to use QML symbian components for desktop application developing too?
I'm currently developing my application using Windows+Visual Studio Compiler + Qt 4.8.1 . But I can't import Symbian components that is reasonable . 
If it is possible to use them how can I obtain and install them?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can if you want. They work well in Symbian Emulator which is a usual Windows application. More over, you can build them from sources and use only those UI components, which you need. [Here](http://goo.gl/u2TCy) I published a sample project, which demonstrates that idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can use them for Desktop apps. However, some Qt Quick components for Desktop exists : http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/